# Which step of this proof needs more justification? (just a sketch)

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $T(f) = \int_{0}^{1} |f|^2 dx$ is continuous where $T: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}.$

Basically I know that $f(x)^2 - f(a)^2 = (f(x) - f(a) )(f(x) + f(a) ) <  \epsilon M.$

I bound $f(x) + f(a) < M$ because $f$ is continuous and continuous functions are bounded.

So $T(f)(x) - T(f)(a) < \epsilon M$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$

The original question had absolute values, but since we are squaring, I am not sure why we need the absolute value.

Also I don't think the question would change if it were from $C(0,1)$ instead of $C[0,1]$ right?

*Technically I could have said $f(x) + f(a) < 2f(a) + \epsilon.$ But then my RHS would include a lot of epsilons.

Comment: Isn't the operator norm just $M$ ( so bounded, continuous)? $||f||_{C[0,1]} :=Sup f(x): x \in [0,1]=M$ by continuity, and $||T(f)||_{\mathbb R}= M^2 $? I know it is not what you asked; just throwing it in.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $|T(f)| \leq M^2$, so T(f) is bounded.

Comment: $T$ isn't linear, I don't think we can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is defined on the space of continuous functions, not in a pointwise sense, so you have to take two continuous functions, $f$ and $g$, which are close in the sup norm and demonstrate that the value of $\lvert T(f)-T(f)\rvert$ is small. To show $T$ is continuous we proceed as follows:

$\lvert T(f)-T(g)\rvert=\lvert\int_{0}^{1}((f(x))^{2}-(g(x))^{2})dx\rvert\le\int_{0}^{1}\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert\lvert f(x)+g(x)\rvert dx\le M\lvert\lvert f-g\rvert\rvert_{C([0,1])}$

where $M=2\max\{\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert_{C([0,1])},\lvert\lvert g\rvert\rvert_{C([0,1])}\}$.

You can obtain continuity from the above estimate. The question would change slightly if you replaced the closed interval with the open interval since we can no longer guarantee that continuous functions are bounded. You will now have to define an appropriate space in which the functions considered are bounded.

Comment: Oh gee, what was I thinking…spot on.

Comment: For the intermediate steps, you did $$\leq \int_{0}^{1} |f - g||f| + \int_{0}^{1} |f - g||g| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f - g||f|_{\infty} + \int_{0}^{1} |f - g||g|_{\infty}$$ is that right?How do we justify $|f| \leq |f|_{\infty}$

Comment: Is it by definition $|f| \leq \sup \{ |f|\}$?

Comment: You got the intermediate steps correct except I bound further by the max of the two sup norms. Recall that $\lvert f\rvert_{\infty}=\sup\{\vert f(x)\rvert\}$ where the sup is over all appropriate $x$. It isn't by definition that the inequality holds although it follows immediately since for any $x\in[0,1]$ $\lvert f(x)\rvert\le\sup\{\lvert f(x)\rvert\}=\lvert f\rvert_{\infty}$.

Comment: I am still confused, what do you mean it is *not* by definition the inequality holds?

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant. Please ignore that. It does follow by the definition of $\lvert f\rvert_{\infty}$ that the inequality holds.

Comment: I also got another stupid question. Why exactly is point wise  convergence not good enough? Since $f \in C[0,1]$, doesn't it follow from my writeup the result would be true for any $a$?

Comment: Continuity of the function $T$ requires that we look at two possibly distinct continuous functions, $f$ and $g$, on $[0,1]$ and compare $T(f)$ to $T(g)$. Notice that $T(f)$ is a number and has no dependence on $x$ so cannot be shown to be continuous by estimating it pointwise.

Comment: But $T$ is a composition, it takes $f$, which takes on $x$

Comment: $x$ is just a parameter which we use to express the integration variable. It alone cannot affect the value of $T$ since $T$ simultaneously depends on all $x\in[0,1]$.